# How would I list down all comments in order of created_at?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I've got:

```
class Article
  include Mongoid::Document

  embeds_many :comments
end

class Comment
  include Mongoid::Document

  embedded_in :article
end
```

Since `Comment` is an embedded document in `Article`. How would I list down **ALL** Comments in order of `created_at`?

Should I structure it so that Comment is not an embedded in `Article` or is there a way with the above schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to query comments out of context of their articles, then clearly comment should be a top level entity and not embedded one.

In embedded case you can use map-reduce or aggregation framework. Regular query language won't help you here.

Comment: Hmm, but in this context, Comment shouldn't be a top level entity. Since Article is. If map-reduce is the only way. Could you throw in a simple example with the schema I described above

Comment: If you're querying comments on their own, it's a top level entity. There may be more than one top level entity. Don't confuse with a root node in some hierarchies.

Comment: You are suggesting that it is fine to have Article->Comment (Comment embedded into Article) and Comment->Article (Article embedded into Comment) just for the sake of pulling all comments and odering by create_at? A bit redundant..

Comment: I'd say, don't embed anything here. Reference article<->comment.

Answer (score 0):

why not just `default_scope :order => 'created_at DESC'`?  (or ASC).

You're going to want them to be in a consistent order across the site anyway.